# Interesting "paradox" from class: Impulse on a rod in a vacuum results in different energy in dependence on point of impulse

Tags: newtonian-mechanics

This question has been somewhat addressed [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/429416/violation-of-energy-conservation-during-collisions-of-a-particle-with-different), but the discussion ended a little too soon in my opinion. (Sadly, I cannot simply comment in the thread due to low reputation).

Say we have a rigid rod in a vacuum. An impulse $\textbf{I}$, perpendicular to the rod, sets its center of mass (CM) in motion with velocity $\textbf{v}=\textbf{I}/m$, independent of position.

If the impulse acts upon the CM, we have only translatory motion with no rotation about the CM. If the impulse acts upon any other point besides the CM, there is not only translatory motion of the CM, but also rotation about it (due to conservation of angular momentum). It can be easily seen that the total energy in the latter case consists of kinetic and rotational contributions in contrast with the former case, where the energy is purely translational.

In other words, the rotating rod carries greater energy from an identical impulse. To me, this is somewhat counterintuitive and quite difficult to explain away simply.

The only good explanation I can think of is that impulses don't ensure a conservation of energy, since they are a product of force and time, not force and displacement, as is the case in mechanical work. I am looking forward to your constructive comments, and apologize in advance if my intuition is clearly flawed.

Answer (score 1):

> In other words, the rotating rod carries greater energy from an identical impulse. To me, this is somewhat counterintuitive and quite difficult to explain away simply.

The linear motion is slower if there is any rotation.

Consider the case when you touch it just at one end and all the motion is rotational.

Comment: So you're saying the CM has no linear momentum when the impulse acts on the end of the rod? I don't think that's correct.

Comment: Hang a coat hanger from a thread and try it. See any displacement from the thread when you push it near the middle? How about when you do it at the end?

Comment: So hitting a rod in a vacuum at one end will not cause any motion of the CM? Let's assume you are correct and that "the linear motion is slower if there is any rotation." Say we label our coordinate system in such a way that its $x$ axis is parallel to the rod at rest. Hitting the rod at $x=0$ (CM), the CM velocity is simply $\textbf{I}/m$. At the other extreme, the very end of the rod at $x=L/2$, the speed of the CM is $0$, following your statement. What is then the function $\textbf{v}(x)$, as the impulse is applied at some arbitrary $x$ away from the CM? Is it linear, quadratic?

Answer (score 0):

> The only good explanation I can think of is that impulses don't ensure
>   a conservation of energy, since they are a product of force and time,
>   not force and displacement, as is the case in mechanical work.

This is correct.

In case, the force is not applied to the COM, the point of contact will be moving faster than the COM, since it will have a rotational velocity in addition to the translational velocity (equal to the translational velocity of the COM). As a result, over the same time interval, the point of contact will be displaced by a greater distance in comparison with the case, when the force is applied to the COM.